# How to get bitcoin price from bitstamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bitcoin

i want to show bitcoin price but there are several exchangers. i want to get from bitstamp only but positions of exchangers are changing and can't get only one

i wrote some code on jquery but i can't finish it

```
$.getJSON('https://chain.so/api/v2/get_price/BTC/USD', function(data) {

    var text = ` ${data.data.prices[1].price} `
    var integer = parseFloat(text, 10)
    var percent = 3
    var display = (integer - (integer/100 * percent)).valueOf()          


    $(".mypanel").html(display.toPrecision(7) + '$');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get request with jquery you should use `$.get()` and I write you code again (jquery version 3.3.1) [get more detail](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var url= "https://chain.so/api/v2/get_price/BTC/USD";
 $.get(url,function(data){
   var text = ` ${data.data.prices[1].price} `
    var integer = parseFloat(text, 10)
    var percent = 3
    var display = (integer - (integer/100 * percent)).valueOf()  
     $(".mypanel").html(display.toPrecision(7) + '$');

 console.log(data);
 })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unqL14gs/4/

Comment: as i know , i need to filter data , but with documentation can't finish

Comment: do you wanna filter with  `exchange` field?